# Ошибка Could not find method provided() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

При сборке приложения в строке `provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'` возникает ошибка:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method provided() for arguments [org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at 
...
```

build.gradle (Module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "frogermcs.io.githubclient"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'frogermcs.io.githubclient.MyTestRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    //Dagger 2
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.14.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    implementation 'com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta3'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.4-android'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'

    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2"
    testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta3"
}
```

build.gradle(Project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics:androiddevmetrics-plugin:0.7'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У Gradle нет scope `provided`. Похоже это к вам попало откуда-то из Maven.
Используйте `compileOnly` вместо него.

```
compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```